# three.js how to look up in the same direction as target after lookAt

Tags: three.js

I have 2 meshes (mesh1 and mesh2). Theey have their own independent "up" direction. I want mesh2 to look at mesh1 so I call:

```
mesh2.lookAt(mesh1.position.x, mesh1.position.y, mesh1.position.z);
```

After that, mesh2's vector up is pointing in some random direction (up2b). I want mesh2's up to point in the same direction as mesh1's up1 vector. I need to rotate mesh2 along Z axis but how much?

```
mesh2.rotateZ(???);
```

[image: situation]

Answer (score 0):

> I want mesh2's up to point in the same direction as mesh1's up1 vector.

If you want both of them to face the same direction, you can simply copy their rotation:

`mesh2.rotation.copy(mesh1.rotation);`

Comment: This does not work because mesh1 is looking elsewhere, I don't want them to have same rotation.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple:
just add this line to your code:

```
mesh2.rotation.z = mesh1.rotation.z;
```

Comment: This does not work because mesh1 is looking elsewhere,